# Inheritance and MediaPlayer

Tags: android, inheritance, android-mediaplayer

I have a class called `CoordMediaPlayer` that inherits from `MediaPlayer`. My `CoordMediaPlayer` must be able to use the `MediaPlayer` methods so It's why I use inheritance...

The problem is that to instanciate a `MediaPlayer` it must use a `MediaPlayer.create()` static method. It's not like if it just calls a constructor and then I can use method of the parent class normally. If I inherit from `MediaPlayer` I can't access to the `create()` method from a class that inherit `MediaPlayer` I guess because it's static method, I can't Override it.

In ideal I would want to have my `CoordMediaPlayer`, this `CoordMediaPlayer` would not contains a `MediaPlayer` object but I would be able to call all `MediaPlayer` methods directly from a `CoordMediaPlayer` instance. It would be still better if I don't have the same kind of static `create()` method in my `CoordMediaPlayer`, this creation would be done when I instanciate my `CoordMediaPlayer`.

The only one way I found to deal with this, is to have a `MediaPlayer` object in my `CoordMediaPlayer`, then my `CoordMediaPlayer` inherit from `MediaPlayer` and override all the methods I need just by calling the method of my `MediaPlayer` object... but that looks kind of weird to me... is there any other way to deal with this kind of situation, without having a `MediaPlayer` in my `CoordMediaPlayer` but call directly my inherited `MediaPlayer` methods ?

This is how I deal with this, my CoordMediaPlayer class inherit from MediaPlayer and at the same time contains an instance of a MediaPlayer and have to override all methods of MediaPlayer I want to use...

**Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    int fileResId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("s2", "raw", context.getPackageName());
    CoordMediaPlayer cmp = new CoordMediaPlayer(context,fileResId);
    cmp.start();
}
```

CoordMediaPlayer

```
public class CoordMediaPlayer extends MediaPlayer  {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Point coordinates;

    @Override
    public void start() throws IllegalStateException {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public CoordMediaPlayer(Context context, int resId) {

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,resId);
    }

    public void setCoordinates(Point coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public Point getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class actually has [public costructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MediaPlayer()) so you don't have to use the create(..) method for contruction. Documentation only suggest to use static methods in some cases.

By the way, the approach you illustrated in your question is called "composition" and is legit and usually thought as better approach than iheritance. Check this stackoverflow response: [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

However I'd recomend to think more about reasons, why do you think you need to inherit from the MediaPlayer class, in your case. I honestly think you don't need to and you can just use own class encapsulating MediaPlayer instance and providing it's own api to the rest of your application.

Comment: Damned... all example I saw about using MediaPlayer used static method so I ddin't even thought to check if there is a public constructor or not... Your link to composition / inheritance is usefull and interesting too. Thank you for your answer it was very helpfull.